# How to restart a Flutter app from the beginning of the main()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to restart my app at some point from the beginning of the **main()** function and not just rebuild the whole widget tree.

Here is an example of my code, the thing is I want to call init() when restart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await init();
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

I have tried to wrap the widget tree with a Restart widget and tried [phoenix package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix)

But both of them just rebuild the widget tree regardless of what is above in main(). I even tried to call the main() directly but it didn't work as expected.

Is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Do you want to call `init` again? Or has it to be a complete restart?

Comment: You could put the logic from `init()` into a `FutureBuilder` inside `MyApp`, and then wrapping `MyApp` into `Phoenix` and call `Phoenix.rebirth(context)` should work.

Comment: I'm very skeptical that re-executing `main()` would actually do what you want.   Simply re-running the code in main will not magically reinitialize global state (e.g. global and static variables and anything referenced by them). Additionally, if you explicitly call initialization functions multiple times, some libraries might not expect that and throw.

Comment: While debugging? Or at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try "Restart App" module

1. Instal from your teminal:

> `flutter pub add restart_app`

2. Import from your dart file:

> `import 'package:restart_app/restart_app.dart';`

3. Call "Restart App" from main():

> onPressed: () {
> Restart.restartApp();}

Have a nice day...

Answer (score -1):

You runApp(YourApp()) again where you want to restart.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BsTs.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).